# Variational calculus for non-linear functionals (area/circumference optimization)

Tags: optimization, circles, area, polar-coordinates, calculus-of-variations

What are the tools for searching for functional extrema if the functional is nonlinear?

I am especially interested in how the area/circumference ratio optimization problem (of which the circle is the solution) is attacked in the language of variational calculus. In polar coordinates,

$$ R[ r(\phi) ] = \frac{\frac{1}{2} \displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}r^2(\phi) d \phi}{\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\sqrt{r^2(\phi)+\dot{r}^2(\phi)}} $$

with constraint

$$r(0) = r(2\pi) = 1$$

How to find $r(\phi)$ such that $R$ is maximized? It does not seem the standard Lagrange-Euler equations work.

Comment: It looks like as $r(\phi) = 1$ is the solution.

Comment: Tell me something I don't know. But how does the variational-calculus-based proof of that looks like?

Comment: To prove that $r(\phi) = 1$ is a maximizer, you can choose $r(\phi) = 1 + \epsilon \cos(n\phi)$ such that $\int r(\phi)^2 d\phi \approx 1+\epsilon$ and $\int\sqrt{r^2+r'^2}d\phi \approx \epsilon n$ so the functional at the denominator has a minimum at $r(\phi) = 1$.

Comment: Variation $\cos(n\phi)$ does not fullfil the constraints for $0$ and $2\pi$. But OK, I can use $\sin(n\phi)$ or shift the integral to $-\pi,\pi$. *But* you propose a very specific set of variations. How can I be sure that there are no other variations (with different form from $\cos(nx)$) which would lead to higher value of the functional? Are the variations you propose dense in the set of continuous functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: OP's variational problem is unbounded from above.

*Sketched proof:* Consider e.g. the test function
$$r(\phi)~=~K(\pi-|\phi|)+1, \qquad K~\in~\mathbb{R}_+, \qquad \phi~\in~[-\pi,\pi].$$
It satisfies the boundary conditions
$$ r(\phi\!=\!\pm\pi)~=~1.$$
Derivative:
$$ \dot{r}(\phi)~=~-K{\rm sgn}(\phi). $$
Area:
$$ A~=~\int_0^{\pi}\! \mathrm{d}\phi~(K\phi+1)^2~=~\frac{\pi^3K^2}{3}+\pi^2K+\pi.$$
Circumference:
$$ C~=~2\int_0^{\pi}\! \mathrm{d}\phi\sqrt{(K\phi+1)^2+K^2}~\leq~2\pi\sqrt{(K\pi+1)^2+K^2}.$$
A short calculation shows that OP's fraction $A/C\to\infty$ for $K\to\infty$.$\Box$

Comment: You propose one specific form of the variation. How can I be sure that there are no others? Or do I mis-interpret what you are saying? Ratio A/C is unbounded from above? How is that related to the fact that it is bounded and maximal for a circle? Is my question wrongly formulated? How should I formulate the question to get "circle" as answer? I think I got lost in your answer. Can you be more explicit?  What are abbreviations "TL"; "DR", "OP"?

Comment: Indeed, it seems my question in wrongly formulated, I should fix the circumference in addition. Your answer is correct...